# Unable to batch process through command-line

Tags: batch-processing, gimp

(Under Windows 7 x64)

I originally tried to use BIMP to apply a cutout effect to a folder but FU-cutout is one of the few that doesn't appear in the plug-in's list. I read somewhere that was because I hadn't install GIMP while customizing to allow compatibility with older plug-in and I de/reinstalled to try and fix this to no avail. So I decided to use script-fu instead but find myself unable to make it work out through the command line.

I have checked on a few sites explaining how to batch script (including the official GIMP doc) and ended with the follow code.

```
(define (hmd-batch-stylize pattern colours smoothness)
   (let* ( (filelist (cadr (file-glob pattern 1) ) )
         )
      (while (not (null? filelist))
         (let* ((filename (car filelist))
                (image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                                          filename filename)))
                (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image)))
               )
            (gimp-brightness-contrast drawable 35 40)
            (FU-cutout RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                               image drawable colours smoothness TRUE)
            (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                         image drawable filename filename)
            (gimp-image-delete image)
          )
       (set! filelist (cdr filelist))
   )
))
```

(I also register the script but for the sake of simplicity I won't add this code here). Then I open the command line and write

```
gimp -i -b '(hmd-batch-stylize "C:\Users\User\Desktop\3\*jpg" 32 1)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

in the gimp directory (I tried the directory where my files are but gimp isn't recognized as a command there). The gimp console starts up, fails to execute a bunch of dlls and a folder (all part of GMIC) with the mention "Exec format error", then I get two "Batch command completed successfully" at which point the command line freezes until I close it.

I searched online for days hoping to find a solution but no one seems to have the same problem as I do so no solution has worked yet. Help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I thought of instead creating a script that would appear in BIMP and act as a middle-man to access the FU-cutout but I can't find how to pass the current image/filename being used by BIMP as an argument. If anyone knows how, I feel that might be my simplest way of working around this problem.

Comment: This script does run when you try it from within GIMP, e.g. in the Script-Fu console?

Comment: Day two now of learning Scheme and script-fu; I could not iterate through the files list using the approach in the documentation (and above), however, this little link does the trick for me http://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Hacking:Code_Snippets/Script-Fu